# How to print a statement everytime when i call function inside class

Tags: python

```
class Test:
    print("This is class Test")
    def meth1(self):
        print("This is meth1")
    def meth2(self):
        print("This is meth2")

a=Test()
```

1. My question is everytime when i call meth1 and meth2 inside class. I need to have statement printed before function print statements say. `"This is from class Test"`
2. output should be like:

   ```
    This is from class test
    This is from meth1

    This is from class test 
    This is from meth2
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood the question. If you want to print a _base statement_ each time a method is called, just create a private method for printing it and call it at the beginning of each class function. Possibly, with further details, the answer can be more accurate

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of decorators. Just like given below

```
def desc_message(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("This is class test")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class Test:
    @desc_message
    def meth1(self):
        print("This is meth1")
    
    @desc_message
    def meth2(self):
        print("This is meth2")

a=Test()
```

The output will be

```
This is class test
This is meth1
This is class test
This is meth2
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't understood your question very well but here is the solution with what i've understood:

- Make a function that contains text which you want to call in other function.
- Call that function in other functions using `self.func_name()`

```
class Test:
    def desc(self):
        print("This is class Test")
    def meth1(self):
        self.desc()
        print("This is meth1")
    def meth2(self):
        self.desc()
        print("This is meth2")

a=Test()
a.meth2()
>> This is class Test
>> This is meth2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the print statement to the instance method:

```
class Test:

def meth1(self):
    print("This is class Test") 
    print("This is meth1") 

def meth2(self): 
    print("This is class Test") 
    print("This is meth2")

a = Test()
a.meth1()
a.meth2()
```

Output:

```
This is class Test
This is meth1
This is class Test
This is meth2
```